# using hibernate criteria to select into value objects

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to find out if it is possible to do the following HQL using the Hibernate Criteria API:

```
String hql = "select new InitialCount(substring(name, 1,1), count(id)) from Person group by substring(name, 1,1)";
```

Where InitialCount is a very simple bean with a string and long contructor:

```
public static class InitialCount {
    private final String initial;
    private final long count;

    public InitialCount(String initial, long count) {
        this.initial = initial;
        this.count = count;
    }
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
        .add(Projections.groupProperty("formulaProp").as("initial"))
        .add(Projections.count("id").as("count"))
            ).setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(InitialCount.class)).list();
```

---

where formulaProp is a property of person mapped with the formula "substring(name, 1,1)"

Comment: If you do this, you must provide setters and getters for the InitialCount attributes.

Comment: It works, thanks; didn't expect it to be that complicated though... and to bad it can do it with constructor setup to maintain immutability.