# Split string in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have query like this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM test.config 
WHERE loginname = 'login' 
AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`value`,',',-1),',',2) BETWEEN '2014-11-05 09:00:00' AND '2014-11-05 10:00:00';
```

value field consist of comma separated value like '1234,2014-11-05 00:00:00'

How can I convert this in hibernate criteria? Any help?

**EDIT**

I tried to use sqlRestriction, but no query results.

```
DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Config.class);
dc.add(Restrictions.eq("loginname",loginname));   
dc.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("substring_index(substring_index(`value`,',',-1),',',2)
between ? and ?", new Object[]{startDate,endDate}, new
Type[]{StandardBasicTypes.DATE,StandardBasicTypes.DATE}));
```

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958222/using-hibernate-criteria-to-select-into-value-objects

Comment: thanks for response. But I think this won't help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. You've forgot the {alias}.

> Apply a constraint expressed in SQL, with the given JDBC parameter. Any occurrences of {alias} will be replaced by the table alias.

So you need to replace `value` with `{alias}.value`.

```
DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Config.class); 
dc.add(Restrictions.eq("loginname",loginname));

dc.add(
  Restrictions.sqlRestriction(
    "substring_index(substring_index({alias}.value,',',-1),',',2) between ? and ?",
     new Object[]{startDate,endDate},
     new Type[]{StandardBasicTypes.DATE,StandardBasicTypes.DATE}
  )
);
```

Remove also extra substring_index. They will have same results.

```
dc.add(
  Restrictions.sqlRestriction(
    "substring_index({alias}.value,',',-1) between ? and ?",
     new Object[]{startDate,endDate},
     new Type[]{StandardBasicTypes.DATE,StandardBasicTypes.DATE}
  )
);
```